# Python error: ImportError: cannot import name 'NSGAII' from 'platypus'

Tags: platypus-optimizer

I am trying to use platypus. I did all the required steps, install with pip, then uninstall and install again and I still get the error "ImportError: cannot import name 'NSGAII' from 'platypus'"

Anyone knows how to fix it ? thanks

here is the code

```
from platypus import NSGAII, Problem, Real


def schaffer(x):
    return [x[0] ** 2, (x[0] - 2) ** 2]


problem = Problem(1, 2)
problem.types[:] = Real(-10, 10)
problem.function = schaffer

algorithm = NSGAII(problem)
algorithm.run(10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

create

```
__init__.py
```

file in your current directory to resolve the import issue

Comment: I created an empty file with this name at the same directory where the other file is but still I get this: ImportError: cannot import name 'NSGAII' from 'platypus' (C:\Users\n.spiliopoulos\.virtualenvs\python_2-PdWyJcXe\Lib\site-packages\platypus\__init__.py)

Comment: the pacakge you install in venv or as gloabal

Comment: Sorry, still don;t understand. What should I do? thanks

Comment: did u know about Virtual Enviroment?

Comment: yes i am using one

Comment: have you activated?

Comment: the venv yes I have